# Angularjs ui route : Check permission before load view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Now I want to check user's permission before loading ui-view in angularjs.
My `route.js` is something like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('app.test', {
      url: '/test',
      component: 'test',
      resolve: {
        delay: function ($q, $http, $window, $state, $timeout) {
          var delay = $q.defer();
          var token = $window.localStorage.getItem('token');
          $http({
            url: "url get profile here", 
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
             'Authorization': token
            }
          })
          .success( function(response) {
          })
          .error( function(response) {
            $state.go('logout');
          });
          delay.resolve();
          return delay.promise;
        }
      }
    })
```

And in template html:

```
<ui-view name="header"></ui-view>
<ui-view name="sidebar"></ui-view>
```

The problem is : when I edit local storage become incorrect `$state.go('logout');` is working. But in `ui-view` from template already call function into controller with name `header` and `sidebar`. How can I block access controller from `ui-view` before check permission is done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This's error because I push `delay.resolve();` not exactly. My code will become :

```
.success( function(response) {
          delay.resolve();
})
.error( function(response) {
          delay.reject();
          $state.go('logout');
 });
```

It's working!!!